# reconstruct window.location.href with if/else statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, indexof, window.location

I have a website with language preferences. When i click the button to change languages, everything works fine. The only issue is whenever I change the language, it takes the user right back to the homepage to http://localhost/en/
However, I have a page that is http://localhost/en/work, or http://localhost/en/work/#integrations. 
I can't figure out how to stay on the same page when I switch languages. I think it has something to do with split and replace, but I'm not sure. This is what I have so far.

That big if statement at the bottom is my failed attempt (very new here). Any suggestions?

```
languageOptions = ['en', 'zh-cn', 'zh-hk', 'jp-jp', 'ko-kr', 'th-th'];
languageDictionary = {
    'en': 'en',
    'en-gb': 'en',
    'en-us': 'en',
    'zh-cn': 'zh-cn',
} 


function checkLanguage() {
    let lang = localStorage.getItem('lang');  
    if (!lang) {
        lang = navigator.language.toLocaleLowerCase();
    }
    if (lang) {
        let userLang = languageDictionary[lang];

        let urlLang = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];

        if (languageOptions.indexOf(urlLang) !== -1 && urlLang !== userLang) {
            changeLanguage(userLang);
        }
    }
};

checkLanguage();


function changeLanguage(lang) {
    if (languageOptions.indexOf(lang) === -1) {
        return;
    }
    localStorage.setItem('lang', lang);
    window.location.href = '/' + lang;
}

if (window.location.hash) {
    window.location.split('/')[1];
    window.location.replace[1](lang);
    window.location.href = '/' + lang + hash;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like  server side issue

Comment: `window.location.href = '/' + lang;` in `changeLanguage()` is not updating/apending to the existing URL, it is overwriting it to be just `/en` (or whichever language).

Answer (score -1):

Plenty of ways to do it, but one way is just split, update, and join

```
var parts = window.location.href.split("/")
parts[3] = "foo"
window.location.href = parts.join("/")
```

You can do it with a regular expression, substrings, etc.

Answer (score -1):

@epascarello is correct. You can use split and join to do what you need.

These are the issues you are having.

You are doing this.

```
let urlLang = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
```

Which returns an array of the url parts.
If you where to use 'http://localhost/en/work/#integrations' it would return.

```
["http:", "", "localhost", "en", "work", "#integrations"]
```

What you want is this.

```
let urlLang = window.location.pathname.split('/');
```

Then assign the new lang.

```
urlLang[3] = 'newLang';
```

Then use it in you url.

```
window.location.href = urlLang.join("/");
```

Which would return 'http://localhost/newLang/work/#integrations'

Comment: **Which returns an array of the url parts"* - I don't think so, not with the `[1]` on the end of that line.